# Who chooses which cards are traded when using the Force Deal?

Tags: monopoly-deal

I was playing Monopoly Deal with my friends and I was just introduced to the game, so when I put down a Force Deal, my friends didn't know either.

Are you meant to give the player a card they want, and they'll give you a card you want?

Or do you give them a card not by their choice, and they'll do the same? Is it meant to be like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both choices are made be the player who played the card. You can't use Force Deal to break up a completed set.

(source: [monopolydealrules.com](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=action))

Comment: So if I put down a Force Deal that means that I can swap with the properties I want to swap?

Comment: If it is not in a completed set then yes